# converge/diverge integral

Tags: integration

I need to tell if this integral converge or diverge:

$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{1-\frac{1}{x}}}dx$.Now, I think this diverge because $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx$ diverge because $\frac{1}{x^{a}}$ diverge for a<=1.
Can you help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Observe that, for $x\geq1$, you have
$$
\frac1{x^{1-1/x}}\geq \frac{1}{x}
$$ giving, for $M\geq1$,
$$
\int_1^M\frac1{x^{1-1/x}}\:dx\geq \int_1^M\frac1x\:dx
$$ then conclude easily.

Comment: I was trying to analyze what happens near $x=0$, where it vanishes to infinite order. (missed the forest for the trees). This is much nicer what my first thought was.

Comment: Yes what's happen when x approaches 0+?

Comment: Like I said, it vanishes to infinite order, and remains bounded on the interval $[0,1]$. In fact, the function is bounded on $[0,\infty)$, but you can show that $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{1-1/x}}\,\text{d}x \leq 1$$
To do so, note that the integrand is increasing on $(0,1)$, and has a local maximum value of $1$, attained at $x=1$.

Comment: The convergence or divergence of this integral was going to be determined by its behavior near $x=0$ or $x\to \infty$, and boundedness near $x=0$ (in fact, the integrand $\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$, and remains bounded everywhere) means that you only need to consider what happens as $x\to\infty$, which is what the above answer does (quite succinctly).

Comment: Nicholas Stull-Thanks for the help! I caught the idea in the interval [1,infinity). But it is difficult for me to understand this in the interval (0,1] and how the function behave near 0+. can you show me how to prove this integral diverge in (0,1].thanks!!!

Comment: never mind!!! I understand!! thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: @Jamie The integral is not divergent near $0$, since the function is continuous on $(0,1]$ and since the integrand tends to a finite limit as $x$ tends to $0$. What produces the divergence is the behaviour of the integrand as $x$ tends $\infty$. Thank you!